# Formula cell in excel shows #NAME?

Tags: java, excel-formula, apache-poi, excel-2007

I am attempting to add an excel formula to calculate Upgrade Effort based on certain conditions that will refer to other columns in the same excel sheet.

Below is my formula

```excel
=@IFERROR(@IFS(C3="css", IFS(D3>0.5, "High",
 D3>0.3, "Medium", D3>0.2, "Low",D3>0,"Very Low", 
 D3=0, "None")),
 IFS(D3>0.5,"High",D3>0.3,"Medium",D3>0.2,"Low",D3>0,
 "Very Low",D3=0,"None"))
```

The value of a formula cell is not evaluated. When you select a cell and press enter, a popup warning appears, and the formula is correctly evaluated.

Sample code

```
import java.awt.Desktop;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFFormulaEvaluator;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class CreateExcekFormula {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        try (Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
                FileOutputStream fileout = new FileOutputStream("ItemFilter.xlsx")) {

            Sheet dataSheet = workbook.createSheet("Data");

            Row row;
            Cell cell;
            String strFormula = "IFERROR(IFS(%s=\"css\", IFS(%s>0.5, \"High\", %s>0.3, \"Medium\", %s>0.2, \"Low\", %s>0, \"Very Low\", %s=0, \"None\")),IFS(%s>0.5, \"High\", %s>0.3, \"Medium\", %s>0.2, \"Low\", %s>0, \"Very Low\", %s=0, \"None\"))\r\n"
                    + "";
            Object[][] data = new Object[][]
                { new Object[]
                            { "Header", "Complexity", "Type of File", "Change", "Upgrade Effort" },
                  new Object[]
                  { "A", "High", "css", "1" },
                  new Object[]
                  { "A", "Low", "txt", "0.4" },
                  new Object[]
                  { "C", "Moderate", "css", "0.4" },
                  new Object[]
                  { "D", "High", "txt", "0.7" },
                  new Object[]
                  { "A", "High", "css", "0.8" },
                  new Object[]
                  { "B", "Low", "css", "0.2" },
                  new Object[]
                  { "G", "Low", "css", "0.1" },
                  new Object[]
                  { "G", "High", "properties", "0.4" },
                  new Object[]
                  { "G", "High", "css", "1" },
                  new Object[]
                  { "G", "High", "css", "0.2" },
                  new Object[]
                  { "G", "Low", "jsp", "0.8" },
                  new Object[]
                  { "H", "Low", "jsp", "0.6" },
                  new Object[]
                  { "H", "Low", "html", "0.4" } };
            for (int r = 0; r < data.length; r++) {
                row = dataSheet.createRow(r);
                Object[] rowData = data[r];
                for (int c = 0; c < rowData.length; c++) {
                    cell = row.createCell(c);
                    if (rowData[c] instanceof String) {
                        cell.setCellValue((String) rowData[c]);
                    } else if (rowData[c] instanceof Number) {
                        cell.setCellValue(((Number) rowData[c]).doubleValue());
                    }
                }
                if (rowData.length < 5) {
                    cell = row.createCell(4);
                    String fileTypeCol = "C" + (r + 1);
                    String changeCol = "D" + (r + 1);
                    String formula = String.format(strFormula, fileTypeCol, changeCol, changeCol,
                            changeCol, changeCol, changeCol, changeCol, changeCol, changeCol,
                            changeCol, changeCol);
                    System.out.println("Formula ====== " + formula);
                    cell.setCellFormula(formula);
                }
            }

            XSSFFormulaEvaluator.evaluateAllFormulaCells(workbook);

            workbook.write(fileout);
            fileout.close();
            Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File("ItemFilter.xlsx"));

        }

    }
}
```

Received outcome:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Excel function `IFS` was introduced after publishing the Office Open XML file system in 2007. Thus not all spreadsheet applications will support this function. To mark this, such functions are prefixed by `_xlfn.` in file storage. That is in `/xl/worksheets/sheet*.xml` using Office Open XML `*.xlsx`.

Because of that prefix spreadsheet applications can detect a function that is not supported in the version of Open Office XML that they are currently running. See: [Issue: An _xlfn. prefix is displayed in front of a formula](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/issue-an-xlfn-prefix-is-displayed-in-front-of-a-formula-882f1ef7-68fb-4fcd-8d54-9fbb77fd5025)

Since Apache POI directly writes into file storage `/xl/worksheets/sheet*.xml`, that prefix must be set using `Cell.setCellFormula`. Wrong is `setCellFormula("...IFS(...")`. Correct is `setCellFormula("..._xlfn.IFS(...")`.

Aditional your code should set numeric values for numbers and not strings. Wrong: `...new Object[] { "A", "High", "css", "1" }, new Object[] { "A", "Low", "txt", "0.4" },...`. Correct `...new Object[] { "A", "High", "css", 1 }, new Object[] { "A", "Low", "txt", 0.4 },...`.

Complete example using your code sample:

```
import java.awt.Desktop;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class CreateExcelFormulaIFS {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  try (Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
       FileOutputStream fileout = new FileOutputStream("./IFSFormula.xlsx")) {

   Sheet dataSheet = workbook.createSheet("Data");

   Row row;
   Cell cell;
    //String strFormula = "IFERROR(IFS(%s=\"css\", IFS(%s>0.5, \"High\", %s>0.3, \"Medium\", %s>0.2, \"Low\", %s>0, \"Very Low\", %s=0, \"None\")),IFS(%s>0.5, \"High\", %s>0.3, \"Medium\", %s>0.2, \"Low\", %s>0, \"Very Low\", %s=0, \"None\"))\r\n"
    //        + "";
   String strFormula = "IFERROR(_xlfn.IFS(%s=\"css\", _xlfn.IFS(%s>0.5, \"High\", %s>0.3, \"Medium\", %s>0.2, \"Low\", %s>0, \"Very Low\", %s=0, \"None\")),_xlfn.IFS(%s>0.5, \"High\", %s>0.3, \"Medium\", %s>0.2, \"Low\", %s>0, \"Very Low\", %s=0, \"None\"))";
   Object[][] data = new Object[][] {
    new Object[] { "Header", "Complexity", "Type of File", "Change", "Upgrade Effort" },
    new Object[] { "A", "High", "css", 1 },
    new Object[] { "A", "Low", "txt", 0.4 },
    new Object[] { "C", "Moderate", "css", 0.4 },
    new Object[] { "D", "High", "txt", 0.7 },
    new Object[] { "A", "High", "css", 0.8 },
    new Object[] { "B", "Low", "css", 0.2 },
    new Object[] { "G", "Low", "css", 0.1 },
    new Object[] { "G", "High", "properties", 0.4 },
    new Object[] { "G", "High", "css", 1 },
    new Object[] { "G", "High", "css", 0.2 },
    new Object[] { "G", "Low", "jsp", 0.8 },
    new Object[] { "H", "Low", "jsp", 0.6 },
    new Object[] { "H", "Low", "html", 0.4 }
   };
   for (int r = 0; r < data.length; r++) {
    row = dataSheet.createRow(r);
    Object[] rowData = data[r];
    for (int c = 0; c < rowData.length; c++) {
     cell = row.createCell(c);
     if (rowData[c] instanceof String) {
      cell.setCellValue((String) rowData[c]);
     } else if (rowData[c] instanceof Number) {
      cell.setCellValue(((Number) rowData[c]).doubleValue());
     }
    }
    if (rowData.length < 5) {
     cell = row.createCell(4);
     String fileTypeCol = "C" + (r + 1);
     String changeCol = "D" + (r + 1);
     String formula = String.format(strFormula, fileTypeCol, changeCol, changeCol,
                    changeCol, changeCol, changeCol, changeCol, changeCol, changeCol,
                    changeCol, changeCol);
     System.out.println("Formula ====== " + formula);
     cell.setCellFormula(formula);
    }
   }

   workbook.write(fileout);
   fileout.close();
   Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File("./IFSFormula.xlsx"));

  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick fix. This hack resolved my problem. Is there any documentation on this subject/setting for the _xlfn prefix?

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/issue-an-xlfn-prefix-is-displayed-in-front-of-a-formula-882f1ef7-68fb-4fcd-8d54-9fbb77fd5025